# Measuring server query time in python

Tags: python

I've been looking at measuring the time taken for a responce to a server query. I know I can use `time.time()` but this is a pretty terrible measure due to it's low tick rate, adjustability and it being non-monotonic. However, as (unless I'm mistaken) `time.process_time()` measures only CPU time and not any time spent at sleep I suspect that also wouldn't work for measuring IO time.

Can anyone suggest a good alternative.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is a IO time? is [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) not working properly for you?

Comment: Time spent waiting for IO response, the script I'm testing queries a server

Comment: so, why don't you use `timeit`?

Comment: You can use `time.perf_counter`

Comment: because a) I'm unsure if it takes into account time spent sleeping and b) it's used for testing the performance of a piece of code rather than actually timing something while the code is running

Comment: @El. does that include the time spent waiting for the response? being a performance oriented counter I assumed it wouldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest `perf_couner` from `time`.

You can utilize it like below:

```
from time import perf_counter

start = perf_counter()
# do some IO
end = perf_counter()
# time spent
print(end - start)
```

Also, you can try [Cprofile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) which gives you more detailed stats.

```
import cProfile
import pstats
import io
from pstats import SortKey

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

# do some IO

pr.disable()
s = io.StringIO()
sortBy = SortKey.CUMULATIVE
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sortBy)
ps.print_stats()
print(s.getvalue())
```

Comment: Would that work? The documentation says that `perf_counter` doesn't include time spent at sleep

Comment: Yes, It's working most of the time. If you want something bullet proof you can try [Cprofile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) which gives you more detailed stats.

Answer (score 1):

What library are you using to do requests? If you are doing a API call with requests, the object should provide you with this information.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
print(resp.elapsed)
```

Please check out the API docs https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response